# Adjust GeoServer home page just to WMS service

Tags: geoserver, wms, boundless-suite

I want to adjust my first GeoServer home page (before logging in) just to **WMS service** 
Can anybody help me please?

[image]

Comment: your users should never see the preview page.

Comment: Do you really want to turn off the WFS everywhere?

Comment: Thanks guys.
No just for first page before logging in!